# Path attribute in form:select - spring 2.5 JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've been put on the task of learning spring (2.5), and I've got into a problem using the  attribute where, when the form is loaded, I wont get any pre-selected values. So the situation is as follows:

In my system I have Companies, Customers and Users. Customer extends Company, and a Company can have a List of Users (the getMethod is public so hence Customer also have a List of Users).

So this is how the form select looks in my .JSP:

```
<form:select multiple="true" id="selectAccountManager" path="${customer.users}"        cssClass="input select_img" >
    <c:forEach items="${customerUsers}" var="user" >                                
        <form:option value="${user.id}                             
            <c:out value="${user.displayName}" />                               
        </form:option
    </c:forEach>                                        
</form:select>
```

Right now, I get an error on the `path="${customer.users}"`. If I use `path="users"` my system works, but then I wont get any of the values within the form as "pre-selected" when the page loads. I've tried with path="customer.users" but when I do this I get a referenceError in js-console.

The .JSP is mapped to an **EditCustomerController** where customerUsers is put into a map by

```
map.put("customerUsers", UserControlHelper.getAllUsers());
```

So I guess this is where the problem lies as I always get **all** users from the system?

TL;DR: How do I set selected values on a form where I load the items from one class, and want the select-filter to come from another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what the problem was.

When I created my map I only put the users in there. What the User-object actually was mapped upon was the id of the user (something I retrieved through ${user.id} as can be seen in the originalpost. What I had to do was to create the path in a correct way as such:

Controller - java:

```
 Map<Int,String> users = new HashMap<Int,String>();

 for(User user: UserControlHelper.getAllUsers()){
    users.add(user.getId(), user.getDisplayName())
 }

 model.put("customerUsers", users);
```

and my jsp:

```
<form:select path="users" items="${customerUsers}"></form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

(First of all, Spring 2.5 is old and I suggest you to use 3.2.x or even 4.0.x)

To pre-select option you should set appropriate field on the model and Spring will pre-select it automagically. Like that:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="myForm">
    <form:select multiple="true" path="users">
         <form:options items="${customerUsers}" itemLabel="displayName" itemValue="id" />
    </form:select>
</form:form>
```

And in the controller:

```
User defaultUser = new User(1, "DEFAULT");
MyForm myForm = new myForm();

myForm.getUsers().add(defaultUser);
model.addAttribute("myForm", myForm);
```